# PHP countdown timer using 'd-m-Y H:i:s' timestamp

Tags: php, date, timer, timestamp, countdown

Im trying to create a timer that for 1 hour from a timestamp it shows a count down then after that shows a form button but I can't get it to work, I have tried multiple methods I found online but they either display the wrong time, or never show the form. Here is what I have so far:

```
while($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
$timestamp = $row2['timestamp'];
$work_id = $row2['work_id'];
$current_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); 
$ready_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($timestamp)+3600);
if($current_time > $ready_time){?>
<form action="" method="POST" onsubmit="return confirm('Are you sure?');">
    <input type="hidden" value="<?echo $work_id;?>" name="work_id">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Complete Workorder">
</form>
?
}else{
$time1 = new DateTime($current_time);
$time2 = new DateTime($timestamp);
$interval = $time1->diff($time2);

echo $interval->d ." Days ". $interval->h . " Hours, " . $interval->i." Mintues, ".$interval->s." seconds"; 
}
}
```

Comment: How specifically is this code not working as expected?

Comment: I could never get a countdown timer to countdown, doesn't have to be realtime just show the time remaining on the page refresh. and as for the $current_time > $ready_time seems to work in reverse and i cant understand why, When the time should have expired (after 1 hour) it still doesnt show the form and always displays my echo Workorder pending

Comment: date/time values from mysql are always in `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` format, e.g. `Y-m-d H:i:s`. if it's coming out of mysql in d-m-Y format, then either you're explicitly requested it that way via `date_format()`, or they're varchar/text values, not datetime. And I don't see any "timer" code in there. you're just sucking some stuff out of mysql and producing a form.

Comment: I have updated my code, i posted an old copy, my mistake. However the timer always reads 0 Days 0 Hours, 0 Mintues, 0 seconds and mitch, you are right and i would like to have it realtime but im not very good a javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the time left in your sql:

```
SELECT work_id, TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),`timestamp`) AS timeleft 
FROM tablename
```

Then check that value in your php:

```
$timeleft = $row2['timeleft'];
$work_id = $row2['work_id'];

if($timeleft >=0): ?>
    <form action="" method="POST" onsubmit="return confirm('Are you sure?');">
        <input type="hidden" value="<?echo $work_id;?>" name="work_id">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Complete Workorder">
    </form>
<?php else: ?>
    <p>You need to wait <?php echo $timeleft;?> seconds</p>
<?php endif;
```

If you want to chow a countdown that actually updates without a refresh, you will need to use javascript, in place of `<p>You need to wait <?php echo $timeleft;?> seconds</p>`

Comment: Thanks, the timeleft is counting up rather than down, and how can i specify how long the wait time required is.

Comment: I dont follow, the above code would output something like `You need to wait 3600 seconds`. If you refreshed the page again 10 seconds later, it would read `You need to wait 3590 seconds`. What issue are you having